Windows API own integer types max and min values
Being forced to program using windows I have approached  a problem. Despite intensive googling I have not found max and min definition for windows inter types like WORD, DWORD.
Do they exist?

constexpr auto word_min = std::numeric_limits<WORD>::min(); should work.  And ::max() for the word_max value;  Likewise for DWORD  Don't forget to #include <limits>.

@Eljay good idea but max() and min() conflict with definitions from minwindef.h macros  Preprocessor expands it to std::numeric_limits<WORD>::((() > ()) ? () : ())

#undef min and #undef max to avoid the conflict with the minwindef.h macros, or use #define NOMINMAX 1 before including that header, or compiler flag /DNOMINMAX=1.

You'd think that those are documented under Windows Data Types.

@Eljay a very good solution. Thank you. I use it in my app

Why not use predefined macros? See Windows Data Types and Data Type Ranges.

Limits are defined in intsafe.h (excerpt below):
#define INT8_MIN        (-127i8 - 1)
#define SHORT_MIN       (-32768)
#define INT16_MIN       (-32767i16 - 1)
#ifndef INT_MIN
#define INT_MIN         (-2147483647 - 1)
#endif
#define INT32_MIN       (-2147483647i32 - 1)
#ifndef LONG_MIN
#define LONG_MIN        (-2147483647L - 1)
#endif
#define LONGLONG_MIN    (-9223372036854775807i64 - 1)
#define LONG64_MIN      (-9223372036854775807i64 - 1)
#define INT64_MIN       (-9223372036854775807i64 - 1)
#define INT128_MIN      (-170141183460469231731687303715884105727i128 - 1)

#ifdef _WIN64
#define INT_PTR_MIN     (-9223372036854775807i64 - 1)
#define LONG_PTR_MIN    (-9223372036854775807i64 - 1)
#define PTRDIFF_T_MIN   (-9223372036854775807i64 - 1)
#define SSIZE_T_MIN     (-9223372036854775807i64 - 1)
#else
#define INT_PTR_MIN     (-2147483647 - 1)
#define LONG_PTR_MIN    (-2147483647L - 1)
#define PTRDIFF_T_MIN   (-2147483647 - 1)
#define SSIZE_T_MIN     (-2147483647L - 1)
#endif

#define INT8_MAX        127i8
#define UINT8_MAX       0xffui8
#define BYTE_MAX        0xff
#define SHORT_MAX       32767
#define INT16_MAX       32767i16
#define USHORT_MAX      0xffff
#define UINT16_MAX      0xffffui16
#define WORD_MAX        0xffff
#ifndef INT_MAX
#define INT_MAX         2147483647
#endif
#define INT32_MAX       2147483647i32
#ifndef UINT_MAX
#define UINT_MAX        0xffffffff
#endif
#define UINT32_MAX      0xffffffffui32
#ifndef LONG_MAX
#define LONG_MAX        2147483647L
#endif
#ifndef ULONG_MAX
#define ULONG_MAX       0xffffffffUL
#endif
#define DWORD_MAX       0xffffffffUL
#define LONGLONG_MAX    9223372036854775807i64
#define LONG64_MAX      9223372036854775807i64
#define INT64_MAX       9223372036854775807i64
#define ULONGLONG_MAX   0xffffffffffffffffui64
#define DWORDLONG_MAX   0xffffffffffffffffui64
#define ULONG64_MAX     0xffffffffffffffffui64
#define DWORD64_MAX     0xffffffffffffffffui64
#define UINT64_MAX      0xffffffffffffffffui64
#define INT128_MAX      170141183460469231731687303715884105727i128
#define UINT128_MAX     0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffui128

